# What is the difference between Prompt() and SpeakAsync(String)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, text-to-speech

I have read the documentation but fail to understand what the underlying difference is between using:

```
Prompt prompt = new Prompt("What are you doing?");
speaker.SpeakAsync(prompt);
```

VS:

```
speaker.SpeakAsync("What are you doing?");
```

The reason I am asking this is because I am trying to get a response from the user and it's not just a statement, I am expecting a specific answer to a question that the speaker asks.

For example, I want `speaker` to say "What are you doing?" and if the user speaks into the microphone, "I'm trying to read, leave me alone.", then the voice recognition should stay quiet.

I am trying to determine how to best handle Question/Answer-based scenarios. How should I handle this, when my app is expecting a specific type of answer so that it can act on it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use Prompt if it is just a simple string.

But more elaborate phrases can be built with PromptBuilder, switching voice and volume, inserting pauses and audio snippets, using Ssml markup, specifying style and pronunciation, marking paragraphs and sentences.  With some further likelihood that you want to preserve that if you repeat the phrase.  You'll need to use the Prompt class for that.

Answer (score 1):

A Prompt object can contain plain text, text formatted with markup language, or audio files.

`SpeakAsync` is of type prompt.

I had to check a tts app I did a while back.